I am wanting to get the correct output for my product price
I am wanting to display the cost of a product without the currency as well as the digits after the number, so instead of "(currency) 14 250.00"  I want it to display as "14,250"
I have managed to get rid of the (Currency) as well as the ".00" but at the moment the price is just displaying at 14250 not 14,250.
How can improve my code to achieve this?
<span class="{{ section.id }}--Rnow-cost"> {%- assign price = variant.price | divided_by: 100 | floor -%} {{ price | number: 0 }} </span>
This is the code I currently Have, and this is the code that is displaying 14250 not 14,250
